# Dynamic css site with button to switch to desktop version on iphone / ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, responsive-design, viewport, mobile-website

I can change the css dynamically, but I can not change vewport dynamically (ie site by clicking the "desktop version" button is not displayed in full size). When desktop icon is clicked, it opens desktop version on iphone but zoomed in..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

// Responsive Design Opt Out - cookie values
c_name = "optoutresponsive";
c_value = "1";
c_expires = 365;

// Responsive Design Opt Out - user actions
function optout() {
  createCookie(c_name, c_value, c_expires);
  location.reload();
}
function optin() {
  eraseCookie(c_name);
  location.reload();
}

$(document).ready(function () {

  // Responsive Design Opt Out - helper functions
  function optedout() {
    if (readCookie(c_name) == c_value) {
      return true;
    }else {
      return false;
    };
  }
  function unlinkcss() {
    jQuery('#mobilecss').remove();
  }
  function printstatus() {
    $('#hv,#fullv').append(" ");
  }
  function renderuserselections() {
    if (!optedout()) {
      resp_html_selectors = "<div class='resp_selector_container'><input class='resp_selector' type='button' onClick='optout();' value='desktop version'/></div>"
    }
    else {
      resp_html_selectors = "<div class='resp_selector_container'><input class='resp_selector' type='button' onClick='optin();' value='mobile version'/></div>"
    }
    $('#fullv').append(resp_html_selectors);
  }

  // Main 
  if (optedout()) {
    unlinkcss();
    printstatus();
  }
  renderuserselections();

});
</script>
```

Comment: How do we need to do:

1. If the screen resolution is less than 480 pixels - viewframe should be:
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
If more than 480 - should be as follows:
<meta name = "viewport" content = "maximum-scale = 1">
2. When the user presses the button "desktop version" - creates a cookie file. Depending on what is written in the cookie file, connect the correct css files and viewport.

Comment: There are 3 cases:
User agent mobile, by default mobile version -> viewport A, css A
User agent mobile, prefers desktop version -> viewport B, css B
User agent desk, only the desktop version -> viewport B, css B

if the user has switched from the mobile to the desktop version, and then decided to go back - css and viewport are changed again at A, A